# How do I start automation using groovy script in soapUI Pro?

Tags: groovy, automation, soapui

I'm new SoapUI Pro with automation. With the help of the SoapUI Pro tool, I have tested only request and response for the service so far. If I want to automate this process by writing script using groovy inside SoapUI Pro tool how do I do it?

What are the per-requisites required to learn Groovy script?

Please anyone guide me..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps for a navie to start SoapUI Test Automation

1. Understand XML DOM (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp) in detail. What's it all about.
2. Understand how SoapUI Works. Go to their [website](http://www.soapui.org/).
3. Identify what exactly is your requirement that you want to automate. It could be as simple as Running a Test Suite for already present/created Test Suite or to Generate Realtime XML Request from bindings, Connecting Excel to fetch data, Generating XML Response and Validating, Generating log etc. Sky is the limit.

Go Step-by-Step and you should be all good to automate SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

Answering here to the initiated question.
You need understanding of any basic programming/scripting, OOP capability/knowledge, REST/Http/Https and JSON/XML.

Don't worry it's all easy, first double click on any test case/suite, you will see it's editor, in that there is a option for "setup script" for before running tests.

Please analyze what all variables on top are listed, like : runner/testRunner, testCase/testSuite, logger, context...etc.
There are methods from which one can get another handle, like from testCase you can get testSuite/teststep via respective methods, so those you need to know.

The idea is to run a testCase/Suite/Step by script, which you already have configured, you can set header for each api and also properties too. You can even do almost everything via Groovy/JavaScript scripting in soapui.

I am actually going to create a blog having required groovy scripts to do automation regarding, REST API execution and testing.
I will be posting that link here.
Thanks!